# Passing Data from a View Controller to a Cocos2D Scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

In my game, I use Cocos2D for physics in the gameplay and UIKit for the menu screen and the rest of the game. Now, I have to pass the data from a UIViewController to a Cocos2D scene. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you need to pass the data when the scene/layer is initialized, or pass the data after that? And how do you initialize the scene in your code?

Comment: I need to pass the data when the scene in initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it by assigning value to a class variable....

Code snippet will look like this...

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameScene scene:data]];
```

in your `GameScene.m`

```
@implementation GameScene
@synthesize ...

+ (CCScene *) scene:(Datatype *)data
{
 self.dataReceived = data;

 CCScene * .....
 .......
}
```

Something like this may help.. I did this in cocos2d-x and it works fine.. M sorry for syntax as I don't have X-code.... :)